# MVC Form generating unwanted code in presnetation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

Whenever I use (@Html.BeginForm()) such as in this example below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownList("test", Model.Select(p => new SelectListItem{ Text = p.Name, Value = p.ID}))
}
```

I get this error:

> Error 2   Cannot use local variable 'Html' before it is declared

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `@` infront of your using, e.g.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) { ... }
```

...and as the commenter pointed out, once you are inside the @using, remove the `@` from infront of `@Html`

Comment: And remove the `@` before `Html`

Comment: @ZippyV before `Html` you mean?

Answer (score 0):

when you are working on razor view
the **@** statement tries to print output to the response.
In your case

```
@Html.BeginForm()
```

the above statement returns the Form object which it is trying to print and results in ToString() method of an object which prints the class name on the browser
You should remove the **@** from the statement and using it with using only.

hence make it like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
// your html
}
```

Comment: can I have another Html tag inside?

Comment: Please Add your entire razor page here